# Cannot resolve method in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a `Question` object that has 4 `Answer` objects inside.

In Question.java I have a method that is:

```
public Answer getA() {
    return a;
}
```

and in another method I have:

```
if (questions.get(randomNum).getA().isCorrect())
                System.out.println("Correct!");
```

where `Questions` is an `ArrayList` containing my `Question` objects.

This gives me a `Cannot resolve method getA()` error and I'm not quite sure why.

For reference:

```
System.out.println(questions.get(randomNum));
```

works perfectly fine in printing out the question and the answers.

Question.java

```
public class Question {
    private String questionText;
    private Answer a, b, c, d;

    public Question(String questionText, Answer a, Answer b, Answer c, Answer d) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }

    public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }

    public Answer getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Answer a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Answer getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Answer b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Answer getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(Answer c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public Answer getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(Answer d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return  questionText +
                "\nA) " + a +
                "\nB) " + b +
                "\nC) " + c +
                "\nD) " + d;
    }
}
```

Answer.Java

```
public class Answer {
    private String answerText;
    private boolean correct;

    public Answer(String answerText) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
        this.correct = false;
    }

    public String getAnswerText() {
        return answerText;
    }

    public void setAnswerText(String answerText) {
        this.answerText = answerText;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect() {
        return correct;
    }

    public void setCorrect() {
        this.correct = true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return answerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: **s** etA vs **g** etA.

Comment: sorry for some reason I copied the wrong method. Corrected.

Comment: Can you show how `questions` is defined?

Comment: you did not post all relevant code

Comment: Edited with all code in my classes.

Comment: Is questions defined like this? `ArrayList<Question>`

Comment: `ArrayList questions = new ArrayList<Question>();`

Comment: Ah, do this instead, `ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();`

Answer (score 8):

Make sure your container (using generics) holds the Question type:

```
ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

That way Java knows which method to call.