# How to cast object to type known only at runtime?

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to do casting by Type to Object at runtime but it doesn't work in that way.
There is some smart way to do that instead of using `instanceOf()` for all options?

```
public <T> void updateUser(final SQLiteDatabase db, final String key, Class<T> cls, Object newVal, String prevVal){
   ContentValues userValue = new ContentValues();
    try {
        userValue.put(key, cls.cast(newVal));
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
    }
    db.update(mDBName, userValue, key + " = ?", new String[] {prevVal});
}
```

Comment: No, I have tried it already...
@azurefrog

Comment: you are aware that casting an object does not change anything, it is just *saying* to the compiler that given instance is of that type (but the instance is not changed, if it was for example a `String`, it will still be (an instance) of `String`, no matter what it was cast-ed to) {primitives are changed by casting}

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just write `userValue.put(key, newVal)`?

Comment: Because I am getting an error from 'put':
"cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String, Object)'

Comment: @nirkov [Cannot resolve method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795894/cannot-resolve-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you show (using [`Class.cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object))) does work, but has the overhead of handling an exception.

A clearer and more concise way of doing this is using the [`Class.isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) method:

```
public <T> void updateUser(final SQLiteDatabase db, final String key, Class<T> cls, Object newVal, String prevVal){
    ContentValues userValue = new ContentValues();
    if (cls.isInstance(newVal)) {
        // cls.cast is only necessary if `userValue` has a value type of T
        // like "Map<String, T> userValue"; if it's "Map<String, Object>" then
        // you can just use "newVal" without the cast.
        userValue.put(key, cls.cast(newVal));
        // You'll want to include "db.update" in the "if"-block,
        // since you need to update at least one field to make it a 
        // valid SQL statement.
        db.update(mDBName, userValue, key + " = ?", new String[] {prevVal});
    } else {
        // Raise some kind of error or log something?
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work also. I get an error from 'put':
"cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String, T)'